# How to fix text content not disappearing in Safari?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, cross-platform

I'm new here and this is my first question : I developed a website for [Kodaklens.ma](https://kodaklens.ma) and have adapted it for most browsers.

Firefox : OK
- Chrome : OK
- Mozilla : OK
- Safari Macbook & iPhone : Problem

I tried to apply the webkit styles but doesn't correct anything. Any help ?

Comment: Can't help if you don't tell us what the "problem" is or what code you used to cause it. Try making a [mcve]

Comment: try using the web inspector in Safari.  Also show us some css?